# Eclipse CDT documentation on C++ autocomplete

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I was trying to set up my development environment on Eclipse CDT for C++ and although the auto-complete is working (it finds classes like vector and such) it shows no documentation on C++ stuff, only C stuff (fopen, fclose, malloc) has documentation appearing on the auto-complete.

Some notes:
I'm using Linux Mint and Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819
I had to manually install g++ on my Linux. I used 'sudo apt-get install g++-4.7' to install it
I had to manually place "/usr/include/c++/4.7.3/" on the GCC C++ Compiler Includes in the Tool Settings in the project properties to get it to compile.

Any ideas on how to get the documentation in there?

Comment: Did you re-index your project after adding the new includes?  For future readers, the include directories can be set using these instructions:  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help on C is provided by [Libhover plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/libhover/). The developers tried to support C++ but seems these efforts did not get much traction.

C++ hover is actually installed by default in CDT. If not, you can install it manually (at CDT site look for "Plugins for C/C++ library hover help." and "Plugins for creating hover help from installed C devhelp documentation").

However, it is not enough. To get hovering help similar to C documentation you have to generate Doxygen XML for your library, e.g. for STL. Details are provided in [hover documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.library.docs%2FLinux_Tools_Project%2FLibhover%2FDevelopers_Guide%2FDevelopers-Guide.html)